# How To Drag A TextView To EditText And Append TextView Text To EditText On Drop?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I'm New To Android, I Have A **TextView** And **EditText** In My Layout. I Want To Drag Text From **TextView** To **EditText**! Need Help Please

My XML File:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:hint="Edit Text"
            android:textColorHint="#607D8B"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Thanks In Advance, Little Help Will
> Be Much Appreciated!

Comment: Thank You Anshu For Correcting The Post

Answer (score 0):

Well, I Solved My Problem By Using Below Code:

````
String MyString = textview1.getText().toString();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("text", MyString);
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

    }
        return true;    
  }

});

textview1.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                                            CharSequence paste = item.getText();
                                            edittext1.append(paste.toString());                                         
                                            break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: break;
                default: break;
            }

            return false;
        }

    });```
````